# Is it valid to use Match in Where-Object and Matches in ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell, foreach, where-clause, race-condition, powershell-5.0

**Short Question**

Is it valid / safe to use the following approach:

```
$SomeArray | ?{$_ -match $Pattern} | %{$Matches.CapturingGroupName}
```

Instead of:

```
$SomeArray | %{if($_ -match $Pattern){$Matches.CapturingGroupName}}
```

---

**Why would you want to?**

- The first approach looks more elegant.
- Potentially there may be some performance improvement; e.g. if there's additional code in the `where-object` or `foreach-object` script blocks which is known to be time consuming (e.g. an IO or network operation).

**More Info**

I've written a lot of code which uses the `-match` statement in a `where-object` (`?{<#...#>}`) filter, then refers to `$matches` in the following `foreach-object` (`%{<#...#>}`) statement.

Before I first did this I tested a lot to ensure that the `$matches` variable always gate the result of the previous match; i.e. to ensure that using the pipeline wasn't allowing that variable to update before moving on to the next element.  I even included code to ensure this was not impacted by race conditions.

**Test Code**

```
$TestMax = 1000 #test 1000 times
$SleepMS = 1000 #wait 1 second between each test to allow the feeding match a headstart on the matches
$Evens = 1..(2*$TestMax)  | %{"$_"} | ?{$_ -match '^(?<EvenNumber>.*[02468])$'} | %{Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $SleepMS; $matches.EvenNumber}
if ((Compare-Object $Evens (1..$TestMax  | %{"$($_*2)"}) ) -eq $null) {":)"} else {":("}
```

- Line 1 and 2 are just so you can tweak how long you have to wait for the test to complete / how thorough the test is.
- Line 3 is the code to be tested:

  - count from 1 to 2000
  - convert each number to a string
  - use `-match` to test if the number is even (NB: this code's just for demoing the issue; I'd never use this approach to test for evenness in reality)
  - wait 1 second; this is in the start of the `where-object` loop to try to create a race condition where the `where-object` can overtake the `foreach-object`; thus changing the `$matches` value before it's read.
  - Return each number which made it to the result.
- Line 4 compares our results with the expected results (i.e. even numbers within our test range, held as strings); showing a smiley if it passes.

This works as expected (i.e. we get a smiley).

**So why the concern?**

I did something stupid... I added a `sort-object` between the `where` and the `foreach` (for justifiable reasons), thinking if there's no race condition when one script block pipes to the next (even when including artificial delays) there wouldn't be an issue when adding additional blocks.  What I forgot is that `sort` has to see everything before it can output the first result; meaning `$matches` will therefore always be the last match.

i.e. Line 3 is now:

```
$Evens = 1..(2*$TestMax)  | %{"$_"} | ?{$_ -match '^(?<EvenNumber>.*[02468])$'} | sort | %{Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $SleepMS; $matches.EvenNumber}
```

Though this completely makes sense where `sort` is used, it also means that there isn't a guarantee that one script block will follow another; even though it did in my original tests.  Therefore is it safe to assume that this behaviour (i.e. what I describe in the original question) will always work as I'd expect so long as I don't include anything between the `where` and the `foreach` blocks; or is this just an assumption waiting to bite me?

**A more readable version of the test code**

```
$TestMax = 10 #test 1000 times
$SleepMS = 1000 #wait 1 second between each test to allow the feeding match a headstart on the matches
$Evens = 1..(2*$TestMax) | %{
    "$_"
} | ?{
    $_ -match '^(?<EvenNumber>.*[02468])$'
} | <#sort | #> %{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $SleepMS
    $matches.EvenNumber
}
$ExpectedResult = 1..$TestMax  | %{"$($_*2)"}
if ((Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Evens -DifferenceObject $ExpectedResult -SyncWindow 0) -eq $null) {
    ":)"
} else {
    ":("
}
```

Comment: PowerShell pipeline is single threaded, so there is no race conditions here. But `sort` is not only thing, that can make your code fail: `?{$_ -match '^(?<EvenNumber>.*[02468])$'} -OutBuffer 1 | %{$matches.EvenNumber}`. Although, IMHO, it is reasonable to assume, that this behavior will not change for compatibility reasons. But I would rather not depend on it: `1..100 | % { [Regex]::Match($_, '^(?<EvenNumber>.*[02468])$') } | ? Success | sort | % { $_.Groups['EvenNumber'].Value }`.

Comment: Ah; I always conceptualise it as each script block as running in its own thread; though I know (when I stop to think) that it's single threaded; thank-you; I'd tripped over my own model.  Really like your solution too; I'd not seen that approach before; will definitely be adding it to my arsenal.